# Modify a JSON value using VBA

Tags: json, vba

I have below JSON structure to modify. I have expected values stored in excel as rows and columns and the template saved in a File

The part of template looks like:

```
"name" : [
          {
           "use" : "official",
            "text" : "MS JOHN DOE II",
            "family" : "DOE",
            "given" : [
              "JOHN"
            ],
            "prefix" : [
              "MS"
            ],
            "suffix" : [
              "II"
            ],
            "period" : {
              "end" : "2019-01-22T14:33:53Z"
            }
          }
        ]
```

Prefix in above template is an array with []
I am writing below code to update the Prefix in above template as below

```
resource ("resource")("name")(1)("prefix") = Cstr(ws.Cells(i,j))
```

But the output JSON has prefix as normal object and not as Array

```
Output :  "prefix" : "ms"
```

How to write the correct syntax? Please help and guide!

Comment: Can you include the rest of the json? And what is a normal object? It looks like you have a string literal where you want a collection added as a value in the dictionary. That is not surprising if you are adding via Cstr(ws.Cells(i,j)). I don't know whether that means you need to declare a collection object and add the Cstr(ws.Cells(i,j)) to that collection then add the collection to the dictionary or whether this is a case of adding the [] before parsing the json string.

Comment: I just wish to update the value in Prefix as 
            "prefix" : [ "MS" ]  and not as 
            "prefix" :  "MS" . I added Cstr to get "" around MS or else its coming without quotes in output

Comment: Is it as simple as resource ("resource")("name")(1)("prefix").Add  Cstr(ws.Cells(i,j))   ?

Comment: Ok so my excel has value "Sr" and template has "MS"
The above code its adding a new value to the Prefix as below

Prefix : [ "MS", "Sr"]
I just want output as
Prefix : ["Sr"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you need to modify an item in a collection. To do this you need to remove that item and replace it with updated value.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub demo()
    Dim col As Collection
    Set col = New Collection
    col.Add "Orange"
    Debug.Print col.Item(1)
    col.Remove 1
    col.Add "Banana"
    Debug.Print col.Item(1)
End Sub
```

Something like:

```
resource ("resource")("name")(1)("prefix").Remove 1
resource ("resource")("name")(1)("prefix").Add Cstr(ws.Cells(i,j))
```